# Getting unique count from a structured text data

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, stringi

I am wondering on how to get the unique number of characters from the text string from a structured dataset. This is a follow up question on my previous post. I would like to get a unique count of apples (coded as App), bananas (coded as Ban), pineapples (coded as Pin), grapes (coded as Grp)

```
    text<- c('AppPinAppBan', 'AppPinOra', 'AppPinGrpLonNYC')
    df<- data.frame(text)

   library(stringr)
   df$fruituniquecount<- str_count(df$A, "App|Ban|Pin|Grp")

   ## I am expecting output as follows:

      text           fruituniquecount
     AppPinAppBan     3
     AppPinOra        2
     AppPinGrpLonNYC  3
```

Comment: `sapply(str_extract_all(df$text, "App|Ban|Pin|Grp"), function(i)length(unique(i)))` ?

Comment: yes it works, thanks! cheers

Comment: Can you describe why "AppPinGrpLonNYC" has a count of 3, for example?  In "text", that specific string appears once....Looking across all strings, "Grp" and "Lon" and "NYC" only appear once... I'm confused how the inputs generate the outputs logic?

Comment: @Soren OP is trying to count the number of unique matches for their regex string `"App|Ban|Pin|Grp"`  in each `text` entry. So in `"AppPinGrpLonNYC"`, "App", "Pin", and "Grp" match, for 3. "LonNYC" doesn't match anything in the pattern so is ignored.

Comment: yes thats right, i am looking for unique and specifically those strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the same idea as the accepted answer at your previous question, then you can do,

```
library(stringr)

sapply(str_extract_all(df$text, "App|Ban|Pin|Grp"), function(i)length(unique(i)))
#[1]3 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can be done with base R, no need for external packages.

```
m <- gregexpr("App|Ban|Pin|Grp", df$text)
df$fruituniquecount <- lengths(lapply(regmatches(df$text, m), unique))

df
#             text fruituniquecount
#1    AppPinAppBan                3
#2       AppPinOra                2
#3 AppPinGrpLonNYC                3
```